# How to set the brithday date before current data using flutter DART language?

Tags: flutter, date

I wanted to make sure that the users cannot add their birthday date after today, and I have searched online to put the initialDate: DateTime.now() to avoid a future date, but it does not work in the program.

```
Container( 
  width: CustomSizes(context).getWidth(context) * .45, 
  child: FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
  name: 'birthday',
  // onChanged: _onChanged,
  inputType: InputType.date,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  format: DateFormat('M-dd-y'),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  labelText: 'Birthday',
),
```

),
)

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `lastDate` to today's date.

`initialDate` is the date that is shown when the date picker is launched.

Comment: Am I putting lastDate: DateTime.now() after the line initialDate?